# Difference between Method and Function?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in c# and have a keen interest to learn c#, but I am confused. When I asked some one what the difference is between Function and method, he said to me that there is no difference, that they both have the same functionality.
Now I am quite confused and want to know from good developers what methods and functions are?

Are they both the same?
If not, then how do I initialize each one??

Is this way to initialize a function correct?

```
public void UpdateLeaveStatus(EmployeeLeave objUpdateLeaveStatus)
```

Please provide proper help as I am new.

Comment: Function is the process-oriented name, method the OO name. Since C# (and VB.NET) are object oriented languages you should use method.

Comment: Mean to say that both are same ??

Comment: VB-Side-note: don't mix up `Functions` in VB.NET with _functions_, they are also methods with return values as opposed to `Subs` which don't return anything (but are also methods).

Comment: Well, the difference is in the spelling. Just like the difference between soccer and football(not American football.)

Comment: And with regard to second part of your question, what do you want help with, function or method?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Both are same, there is no difference its just a different term for the same thing in C#.

[Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29):

> In object-oriented programming, a **method** is a subroutine (or procedure
>   or **function**) associated with a class.

With respect to Object Oriented programming the term "Method" is used, not functions.

Comment: the quote implies that there **is** a difference, and that a method is a **special case** of a function. please change your answer to reflect this.

Comment: @EliranMalka, there is no difference between a method and a function in C#, do you know any **function** in .Net framework ? It is mostly a matter of opinion, but most are of the view that in OOP there is only a method, See [another answer on the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/155633/961113)

Comment: i don't care about the implementation (C#), i was just saying the answer contradicts itself.

Comment: @EliranMalka, where do you see method is a special case of function in the quoted statement in answer?  for me it means a method is a subroutine/procedure or a function, so it could be any of those three things.

Comment: correct - if a method **is** (a kind of) a function **that is associated with a class**, there is a difference, hence they're **not** the same. just plain logic

Comment: @EliranMalka, so do you see a "function" in C# ?

Comment: again, i'm not referring C#, just the abstract concept of functions vs methods. maybe i'm too meticulous here, but semantics matter.

Comment: @EliranMalka, well the question is tagged in C# :) but again it is about terminology and everybody's own definition/understanding.

Comment: See @Vitali Kaspler's answer for a clearing up of this semantic argument.

Comment: @Habib They're not the same thing in C#. Take a look, for example, at [anonymous functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx) and [anonymous methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx).

Comment: There are several kinds of functions in C# namely methods, constructors, properties, events, indexers and finalizers etc.

Answer (score 84):

When a function is a part of a class, it's called a method.

C# is an OOP language and doesn't have functions that are declared outside of classes, that's why all functions in C# are actually methods.

Though, beside this formal difference, they are the same...

Answer (score 15):

In C#, they are interchangeable (although method is the proper term) because you cannot write a method without incorporating it into a class. If it were independent of a class, then it would be a function. Methods are functions that operate through a designated class.

Answer (score 3):

There is no functions in c#. There is methods (typical method:`public void UpdateLeaveStatus(EmployeeLeave objUpdateLeaveStatus)`) [link to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28VS.80%29.aspx)
and functors - variable of type `Func<>`

Comment: All methods are functions.  Not all functions are methods.

Comment: Did you read my link to msdn? There is no term "function" in c#.

Answer (score 3):

well, in some programming languages they are called functions others call it methods, the fact is they are the same thing. It just represents an abstractized form of reffering to a mathematical function:

```
f -> f(N:N).
```

meaning its a function with values from natural numbers (just an example). So besides the name Its exactly the same thing, representing a block of code containing instructions in resolving your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Both are the same, both are a term which means to encapsulate some code into a unit of work which can be called from elsewhere.

Historically, there may have been a subtle difference with a "method" being something which does not return a value, and a "function" one which does. in C# that would translate as:

```
public void DoSomething() {} // method
public int DoSomethingAndReturnMeANumber(){} // function
```

But really, I re-iterate that there is really no difference in the 2 concepts.

Comment: I always thought of it as function are stateless, and methods are functions that use/change the state of the object the function is associated with.

Answer (score 3):

*From Object-Oriented Programming Concept*:

If you have a function that is accessing/muttating the fields of your class, it becomes method. Otherwise, it is a function.

It will not be a crime if you keep calling all the functions in Java/C++ classes as methods. The reason is that you are directly/indirectly accessing/mutating class properties. So why not  all the functions in Java/C++ classes are methods?

Answer (score 2):

Programmers from structural programming language background know it as a function while in OOPS it's called a method.

But there's not any difference between the two.

In the old days, methods did not return values and functions did. Now they both are used interchangeably.