# Declare and define a delegate in one line (without using Action/Func)

Tags: c#, delegates

Is there a way to shorten the following:

```
public class Test
{
    /* declares a delegate type (named MyDelegateType) which has a single parameter of 
        type float and doesn't return anything. */
    public delegate void MyDelegateType(float f); 

    /* defines a reference to an object of type MyDelegateType */                                                
    private MyDelegateType MyDelegateRef;

    ... // say we have a Property to set and get MyDelegateRef, and a method
        // for executing its target
}
```

into one line, without using Action/Func types?

I'm asking this to understand if there's an equivalent to what we can do in C++ (or C) with a function pointer:

```
class Test
{
   /* defines a pointer (named MyFP) to a function with a single 
      parameter of type float, and doesn't return anything */
   void(*MyFP)(float); 

   ... // say we have a Setter & Getter functions, and an Execute 
       // function for executing MyFP
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want a 'Func'? As far as I understand with very limited C++ knowledge a function pointer also is some kind of a 'Func' type.

Comment: Why without those type that do just what you want?

Comment: @ThomasSchremser, a function pointer can function either as `Action` or `Func` type. It's not that I don't want a `Action`/`Func`, this question is purely asked to understand the syntactic possibilities.

Comment: The C# language in general does not permit declaring a type in the same statement as declaring an object of that type.  Works in C++ but a never-ending source of very hard to diagnose compiler errors, particularly so if the declaration is in a header file and is missing a semi-colon after the closing brace.  Everybody forgets.  The C# team was made up from very experienced programmers that knew C++ well, including all its traps.  And aimed to avoid them.  Using the Func<> type works because that one is of course already declared.  You'll get used to it easily.

Comment: Just adding this for a related reference: Eric Lippert's [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36560177/6474510) about (not) supporting function pointers in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's why `Action<T>` and `Func<T>` were included in the framework.